# How to get deleted mails of an exchange client from my Administrator account?

Tags: email-server, exchange-2010, mailbox

We have Exchange 2010 in our organisation. One of our team left his job and delete all sent mail from his boxmail. How do I get deleted mails of this X-member from my Administrator account ?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any sent mail that is deleted will go to the deleted items folder and can be recovered from there, if the deleted items folder has been emptied then the items will be placed in the recoverable items folder for a period of time and can be accessed from there. here is a link to info about the recoverable items folder:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364754(v=exchg.141).aspx

and here is another:

http://msexchangeguru.com/2013/03/29/totaldeleteditemssize/

if the recoverable items folder has been emptied then you might have to restore from backup.

If you have the rights to perform e-discoveries then you can search the x-members mailbox and place the items in the discovery mailbox for you to view.

Here is a link on multi-mailbox search that might help you:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335072(v=exchg.141).aspx

Good Luck!